# Crontab will not execute python

Tags: python, linux, cron, centos7

In advance, thank you for looking at my issue community,

My python test script will not execute from my Centos 7 Crontab. This script will execute manually if called either in the containing directory or from the root/any other directory with a full path. My Centos Python location is `/bin/python`. This is included at the top of my python script.

Crontab itself seems to be working fine as:

```
* * * * * root date >> /home/test.log
```

redirects output to test.log without issue.

Please find both my Crontab and test script.

Crontab in /etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
#PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root


* * * * * root python /scripts/test1.py
```

As for the python script in /scripts/test1.py:

```
#!/bin/python
import os
os.system('date >> testlog.txt')
```

Any input/advice you can offer I would greatly appreciate.
Thank you kindly,

Comment: instead of `date >> /home/test.log` try `echo $PATH >> /home/test.log` to ensure the path is as expected.

Comment: You're probably better off putting full path information in the command itself, including where the output goes (not current directory): `* * * * * root /bin/python /scripts/test1.py` and, in the script: `os.system('date >> /tmp/testlog.txt')`

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for the 101 observation. In my python script, I was assuming it would've automatically known the path...shame on me. Thank you very kindly! If you create an answer, I will select yours as the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The environment created by `cron` is quite often nowhere near as complete as that found within a shell. To that end, you're probably better off putting *full* path information in the command itself (so as to not rely on the global `crontab` settings).

In addition, the working directory is also probably not what you'd expect so it's a good idea to either fully specify the file path in the Python script or, preferably since it puts all control information in one place, ensure it's set up in the `crontab` entry.

```
* * * * * ( cd /tmp ; root /bin/python /scripts/test1.py )
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is that trigger the python script from the shell script. Inside the shell script export the PATH variables  before calling the python script as:

python_trigger.sh

`export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
...python -u <your script>...`

And configure your shell script that you normally do using cron.

Comment: Thank you Ramesh! This method also seems to work. Due to my low ranking I cannot publicly up vote you but when I attain 15 rep. I will return to upvote!